# Is there a way to get extra immediate actions?

Tags: dnd-4e

In 4.0, are there any items, feats, powers, etc. that allow you to take more than one immediate action per round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Kind of**

There are a number of epic feats for most defenders that provide them with a second (or rather free first) punishment per round. There are no general case "take a second immediate action" abilities.

These were published in Dragon 387 and are:

- Rapid Aegis Reaction (Swordmage)
- Rapid Combat Challenge (Fighter)
- Rapid Mind Spike (Battle Mind)
- Rapid Wild Defense (Warden)